# formula transformation derivative trick

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential

I have the function f(t). Is there any reshaping trick to get from $\frac{1}{2}\frac{f'^2}{f^2}$ to  $\frac{f''}{f}$

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate $ \dfrac {f'}f$:
$$\left (\dfrac {f'}f\right)'=\dfrac {f''}{f}-\dfrac {f'^2}{f^2}$$